# roughike Bottombar cannot resolve method 'attach

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation

I think I am going crazy. I have been following different tutorials to try and implement roughike's Android BottomBar lib into study projects. The main example on the github repo works fine(using tabs) but when I try the example that points at using menus the code breaks once it encounters this lines:

```
    import com.roughike.bottombar.OnMenuTabClickListener;

    import com.roughike.bottombar.OnMenuTabClickListener;
    mBottomBar = Bottombar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
```

And even if the code looks exactly the same as the examples it will still not work.

When I look into the BottomBar class declaration I also see that it has no attach() method, furthermore someone pointed out that it could be because the attach method was from an earlier version. I find this highly unlikely since most examples I have seen are only from a couple of months back and even if it was updated I believe that the author of the lib would have pointed it out in the github repo.

Am I missing something? or am I going crazy with android studio? cleaning and rebuilding the project does absolutely nothing.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what is your copiled sdk , build tool and bottom-bar version

Comment: @shuvro that would be SDK 24, Android studio's Gradle and the library is version 2.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this library is great, there are a lot of compatibility issues. And it's very heavy (40mb). I'd suggest you to try and use [this library](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) instead. It's works perfectly out of the box, has almost the same functionality, but it's lightweight (5mb) and has less compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks man I  did check it out s you mentioned and it looks pretty straightforward. Definitely much simpler to use than roughike's and perfect for what I need.